# What does 'a slither of' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

While reading a book, I came across this sentence:

> [...], finishing with a slither of lemon tart or apple cake.

Looking up the word **slither** I didn't get any satisfying results.

On OALD I found the definition of "*[to slither](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/slither)*" which means to move forwards either in a smooth way (to slide) or uncontrolled (to glide).

In the given sentence this would only make sense if it's about how smooth this lemon tart goes down the gullet. But I don't think that it is meant like this. Moreover, wouldn't it be "*a slithering lemon tart*"?!

Thinking about the sentence and what it could be I'm assuming that it could mean "*a part of*", but I don't find any proof.

So, which is the correct meaning of "*a slither of*" and which words are best synonyms for it?

Comment: Rather than stick my oar in on the extended debate under Matt's (IMHO totally correct and exhaustive) answer, I'll just say here that so far as I'm concerned, it's an [eggcorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) - probably used unwittingly by many, but deliberately by a few. I can't find a written instance of *a slither of ripe camembert cheese*, for example - but that would strike me as creative writing rather than ignorance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: No one has mentioned any kind of reason why one might make such an eggcorn (if it can be labeled such; I think it can). I would hazard that it's actually hypercorrection in Estuary English, -th-fronting a medial or final dental fricative to a bilabial fricative, voiced in this instance, like 'bruvver' for 'brother'. And since 'sliver' sounds like fronting is going on, it is hypercorrected back to the wrong 'sliver'.

Comment: As always, verbs can be nouned and vice versa. _Slither_ is a member of [the `SL-` phonosemantic class](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/sl.pdf) of English simplex words, which features three largely overlapping semantic features: (1) liquid/solid interface (_sloop, slather, sleek, sluice_); (2) two-dimensional contact (_slalom, slate, slope_); and (3) pejoratives formed from such contacts (_slattern, slave, slouch, sleazy, slum_). Together these make up about 84% of the words and their meanings. Words of a feather flock together.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a misspelling of [sliver](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sliver)

> any small, narrow piece or portion

So *a slither of lemon tart or apple cake* really means *a **sliver** of lemon tart or apple cake*. It is implying a thin slice of the cake or pie.

Apparently this mistake has made it into common parlance, as attested by [this entry from oxforddictionaries.com](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slither?q=slither)

> *Slither* **noun** - a sliver

As we can see from [the origin of slither](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=slither&searchmode=none)

> O.E. slidrian "to slide on a loose slope," a frequentative form of slidan "to slide" (see slide). Meaning "to walk in a sliding manner" is attested from 1848. In ref. to reptile motion, attested from 1839. Related: Slithered; slithering.

when compared to [the origin of sliver](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sliver&searchmode=none)

> late 14c., from obsolete verb sliven "to split, cleave," from O.E. toslifan "to split, cleave," from P.Gmc. *slifanan.

They are not related. It isn't until the beginning of the 1900s that *slither* appears where *sliver* should, in writing.

[image: "slither of" vs "sliver of" NGram]

Comment: Interesting. Do you know, is it common to use slither instead of sliver or just local, informal, ...?

Comment: It is a mistakes. The words do not mean the same thing. Although Google seems to indicate that the mistake happens a lot. You should never use *slither* to mean *sliver*.

Comment: Veronica Henry: **Wild Oats** [Penguin Books, July 2004] www.pagemonger.com/vh/WildOats-VeronicaHenry.pdf -- "You could have a full-blown meal just by sampling what was on offer at Ludlow market, starting with marinated olives, moving on to cured meats and
home-baked breads, finishing with a slither of lemon tart or apple cake."

Comment: @Kris That quote is from someone who was apparently kicked out of school because she spent all her time at nightclubs and never did her grammar homework: http://www.veronicahenry.co.uk/biog.html

Comment: matzos and a slither of rubbery cheese, a slither of light from the Vegas Strip, the slither of light the headlights managed to cast, the far away lake with its slither of blue sky, a slither of silver skips across the rushing wake,  the slither of beach in the distance,  a small blue-gold slither, I'll break your neck for endangering my slither

Comment: [See](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slither?q=slither) *noun* **2** a sliver: *a slither of bacon*

Comment: @z7sgѪ - maybe this is one for the earcorns? ;)

Comment: @z7sgѪ I've update the answer

Comment: Now I am a little bit interested into history, why this 'mistake' happens so often and becomes usual.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: Yet, not far from 'Oxford Dictionaries' [see z7sg...]. Nor did I, for that matter. (the homework part, I mean.)

Comment: @Em1: It's no longer a mistake now.

Comment: @Kris It's way easier to change the existing answer. ;)

Comment: @MattЭллен I don't think this counts as an eggcorn tbh but please do pass on all suspected eggcorns!

Comment: Fine, Matt is as much my friend as you are!

Comment: @Matt Эллен Thanks for amending your answer. Very interesting.

Comment: That’s not the OED; rather, [this is the OED entry](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/181949)  for the noun *slither*. Sense **4b** is: ‘Something smooth and slippery; a smoothly sliding mass; = **sliver** n.1’. The first citation for sense **4b** is: ‘1919 E. Pound *Quia Pauper Amavi* 40 — If she goes in a gleam of Cos, in a slither of dyed stuff, There is a volume in the matter.’ Another citation is: ‘1981 *Daily Tel.* 27 May 15/1 — Calvin Klein’s newest dress is a slither of silk shaped simply like an overgrown T-shirt.’ **I do not think it is always a typo.**

Comment: @tchrist I meant OED in terms of it being from *a* dictionary publish by OUP.

Comment: @MattЭллен I think it as best misleading to use ‘the OED’ in the sense that you used it. I would spell out the name of the dictionary in full rather than risk misleading people into quite naturally believing that ‘OED’ means ***the** Oxford English Dictionary*. And as noted, the real OED gives one reason to believe that *slither* is not always a mere type for *sliver* as you assert, but rather its own word.

Comment: @tchrist I also don't believe it is a typo. I believe it was originally a misspelling, and has come to be a word recognised to have the exact same meaning.

Comment: @MattЭллен Sorry I typo’d *typo* into *type*. I can’t see anything in the OED’s *slither* that suggests it’s a typo for *sliver*. It gives a cogent historical use as a noun deriving from the verb to mean something smooth, slippery, and sliding. Sense 4a is ‘A slipping or sliding. Also *transf*. and *fig*.’ 1st cit is ‘1861 Trollope *Tales of all Countries* 67 — Then there was a great slither, and an exclamation, and the noise of a fall.’ It’s sense 4b (which I previously gave) that lists *sliver* as a synonym. I think the noun *slither* has its own legit history apart from a mere typo. See?

Comment: @tchrist — but a sliver of cake is not slippery, smooth or sliding.

Comment: @tchrist I cannot see the OED but surely it doesn't contradict the free online dictionary?  Because sense 4b is not a synonym of *sliver* (a thin, narrow piece of something).

Comment: @z7sgѪ: I'd prefer to say that 'surely the free online dictionary doesn't contradict the OED'. Surely there's something to be said for precedence and prestige.

Comment: I keep seeing 'slither' used instead of 'sliver', most recently in a national newspaper! This answer has given me satisfaction! Please accept a 50 point bounty as an additional reward.

Comment: @EleventhDoctor glad to be of service

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without knowing the source, but while Matt is certainly correct that a "sliver" would be more conventional, and that it could be an eggcorn or mis-spelling -- it's also entirely possible that it is deliberate.

A poet or a creative writer will often use words that outside their expected context, to sneak meaning and emotion in.

A delicately made lemon tart filling will indeed slither down your throat, and to describe your dessert as a "slither of lemon tart" gives the reader that sense.